# Get json data from mysql in Android 6.0

Tags: android

How to can I get json array from server in marshmallow. I have tried HttpPost and HttpClient but it's show as deprecated. 
Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle file, your application tag should be like this :

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion '23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // this is what you need
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file on your server which catches the values you want and convert them into json.

Then, in your android project, use those object (find documentation and learn how to use them):

```
HttpParams 
DefaultHttpClient 
HttpPost 
HttpResponse 
HttpEntity
BufferedReader 
StringBuilder 
JSONObject
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think HttpURLConnection is use for marshmallow but don't know how to use it.